# open a url link in a new tab from a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I've been trying to open multiple pdf's in new tabs automatically from my rails controller, but nothing has worked so far so I'm back to square one. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated! Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
id_array = [1,2,3]

id_array.each do |id|
  // I want to open each of these three links in a new browser tab
  http://localhost:3000/pdf/id.pdf
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: do you mean on a page rendered from one of you controllers you would like to automatically open up 3 new windows or tabs, each containing the links to pdf?   You will need to use Javascript to do so, and you might run into issues with the browser stopping / complaining about the page trying to open multiple windows.

Comment: this link for example: http://localhost:3000/pdf/1.pdf would render a view. i just need to open a bunch of these links at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should respond with a `javascript` file.

```
<% id_array.each do |id| %>
   window.open('<%= "http://localhost:3000/pdf/#{id}.pdf" %>', '_blank');
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Can open files in new browser window using send_file method. Use :disposition => 'inline'

Eg: send_file "#{Rails.root}/pdf/id.pdf",:filename => 'id.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'